# Which verb to use for taking part in a lesson as a student?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the best way to say that I took part in a lesson as a student? *Mi ???-is lecionon. ?*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would say: *Mi partoprenis lecionon.*

Answer (score 8):

If you were not feeling particularly involved that day, you could say simply *ĉeestis* ("attended") or even *trasidis* ("sat through").